# What is the best way to do multiple designs?

Tags: php, html

This question have probably been asked here before but i dont know what it and how to properly name it.

Heres my objective:
Im trying to make multiple designs for separate pages. Example I have a homepage design but i also have a separate design for my login page and member are page. I usually use a header.pp and footer.php and put content in between but i dont see how that can be done here.

Example of what im trying to do is http://instagram.com/ you see how the homepage has its own design then when you hit login it has it own design with no elements from homepage how can i do that and move away from my header and footer design system.

Comment: a template engine comes to mind

Comment: use wordpress or drupal or joomla or smarty or ....                               http://adaptivethemes.com/using-multiple-templates

Answer (score 1):

Surely just don't use your header and footer temps and make new ones instead, or make a new style sheet for any pages requiring a different design.

Comment: I thought of doing this should i really make a header for each seperate page? such as login-header.php, members-header.php, etc

Comment: @MrJohnson not for each page, but for each section that looks differnt. So for example header-common.php header-login.php

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PHP Frameworks, they have a concept called `layout` from the example you showed of instagram the home page and login page consist of two separate layout files. Layout files are essentially a mixture of the header and footer file together with a placeholder variable to inject the content of the page. You can also implement such a pattern on your code without the use of framework. But least you will need to implement a MVC pattern for it all to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **templates**. PHP is after all a webpage-template-language so it can be done very easy.

I wrote a simple tutorial a while ago on how to do this on your own.

http://gustavsvalander.com/how-to-create-your-own-template-engine-using-php-files/

### The function

```
<?php
// Load a php-file and use it as a template
function template($tpl_file, $vars=array()) {
    $dir='your-app-folder/view/'.$tpl_file.'.php';
    if(file_exists($dir)){
        // Make variables from the array easily accessible in the view
        extract($vars);
        // Start collecting output in a buffer
        ob_start();
        require($dir);
        // Get the contents of the buffer
        $applied_template = ob_get_contents();
        // Flush the buffer
        ob_end_clean();
        return $applied_template;
    }
}
```

### The template

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### How to use

```
<?php
require "template.php";
$template_vars = array('title'=>'Test', 'content'=>'This is content');
echo template('header');
echo template('template_for_firstpage', $template_vars);
echo template('footer');
```